# CSS3 transition chrome and winxp / debian

Tags: css-transitions

CSS3 animation works fine for Opera Firefox and Safari in WIN7 WINXP Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian Squeeze. WIth Chrome it's fine under WIN 7 (Chrome 21.1.1180.89m )and Ubuntu12.04. (21.1.1180.89) but not using same versions under WINXP and Debian Squeeze).

See demo site http://www.hiddenwell.org.uk which contains simple example (view source shows the code).

Object is to move one sentence (and rotate the other) when hovering over the given words.
In Win XP and Debian the first time I "hover" - nothing happens - but a second "hover" activates the animation. All then fine until cache refreshed when the problem starts again. With the other browsers listed and also Chrome when using WIN7 and Ubuntu - it all works fine first time.

Identical situation arises with another more complex animation which starts on page loading. Here I use the @keyframes function to drive the animation. In this instance for Chrome (WIN XP and Debian) the screen freezes and I need to "refresh" to get animation. It works first time in all other scenarios listed.

Anyone any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved with the beta version of chrome now available for WIN XP and Debian Squeeze - i.e. version 23.0.1271.17 beta.

Thanks to the Chrome team for sorting this.

I'll leave my mini-demo on my website for a week or so - so others can see the effect.

(Issue is also resolved with more complex animation discussed above - I can now push on developing another website where I hope to use latest CSS3/animation techniques)